# How to set the IP address and Peer IP Address of a TUN interface in C

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, drivers, c

I am a student working on a moon rover for CMU and need to work with a TUN interface communication between two devices on the rover. I can create a TUN interface, but am unable to assign its IP addresses in C.

Here is the current state right after making the TUN device:

```
41: tun11: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 500
link/none
```

Here is the desired state:

```
14: tun71: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 500
link/none 
inet 192.168.0.29 peer 192.168.0.23/32 scope global tun71
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have tried setting the dstaddr for the ifreq to no avail.

```
int fd;
int dst_fd;
struct ifreq ifr;
struct sockaddr_in* addr;
struct sockaddr_in* dst_addr;

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
dst_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

memcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "tun11", IFNAMSIZ - 1);
addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_addr;
dst_addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_dstaddr;

inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_address, &addr->sin_addr);
inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_address, &dst_addr->sin_addr);
int err;
if ( (err = ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr)) == -1 ) {
    perror("ioctl SIOCSIFFLAGS");close(fd);exit(1);
}
```

I don't know what else to do. I have tried debugging IP after giving it a command to do this, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't got one already, [create a test tun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003684/how-to-interface-with-the-linux-tun-driver):

```
# ip tuntap add mode tun dev tun0
# ip address show dev tun0
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
```

This looks pretty similar to what's in the question. Now to [see what code we need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308090/set-ip-address-using-siocsifaddr-ioctl)...

```
// uptun.c - set an IP address and UP a tun
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>             /* offsetof */
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#if __GLIBC__ >=2 && __GLIBC_MINOR >= 1
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#else
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#endif

// TWEAK
#define IFNAME "tun0"
#define HOST "192.168.0.29"

#define ifreq_offsetof(x) offsetof(struct ifreq, x)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct sockaddr_in sai;
    int sockfd; /* socket fd we use to manipulate stuff with */
    int selector;
    unsigned char mask;

    char *p;

    /* Create a channel to the NET kernel. */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    /* get interface name */
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, IFNAME, IFNAMSIZ);

    memset(&sai, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    sai.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sai.sin_port   = 0;

    sai.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);

    p = (char *) &sai;
    memcpy((((char *) &ifr + ifreq_offsetof(ifr_addr))), p,
           sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr);
    ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr);

    ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING;
    // ifr.ifr_flags &= ~selector;  // unset something

    ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives us:

```
# make uptun
cc     uptun.c   -o uptun
# ./uptun
# ip address show dev tun0
5: tun0: <NO-CARRIER,POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.0.29/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

which only lacks the peer address. Some altagoobingleduckgoing reveals
that tun have a `SIOCSIFDSTADDR` (set destination, duh) in addition to
`SIOCSIFADDR`. Let's jam that into the script right after the
`SIOCGIFFLAGS` line...

```
        // KLUGE copypasta in the destination address
        sai.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.23");
        p = (char *) &sai;
        memcpy((((char *) &ifr + ifreq_offsetof(ifr_addr))), p,
               sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFDSTADDR, &ifr);
```

and after a compile and re-run of `uptun` we have:

```
# ip address show dev tun0
5: tun0: <NO-CARRIER,POINTOPOINT,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.0.29 peer 192.168.0.23/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: This answered my question. Thank you so much!